# How does one quickly access ruby and rails documentation when using vim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

What method are vim users out there using to quickly access documentation for both ruby and rails  (other than switching to the browser to use [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/) or [railsapi](http://railsapi.com/)?).

I was trying to adapt this script (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Online_documentation_for_word_under_cursor) to do the trick however it's only going to work if the cursor is over a class name and I'd like it to work with both class and methods.

Thanks.

Comment: Uh, easy with sarcasm bro. Have tried using ri by using the K shortcut but b/c all my gems are also on the ri path, I usually end up with a list of methods that match, more than what I need. I guess I could alter the ri lookup path but was just curious how others are doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you may have answered this yourself with that function, but there are a couple of existing Vim plugins that can access ri on-the-fly within Vim. I use [PA_ruby_ri](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2706). You might also try [ri-browser](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=494) and [ruby-menu](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=188), though I can't personally vouch for either of them.

Comment: Thanks! This is the sort of info I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to modify the script in the OP to work with the slick http://railsapi.com (which also provides docs for ruby, rspec and more).

Added the below to my .vimrc, then using leader + d will load up the docs for the word the cursor is on:

```
" online documentation search
function! OnlineDoc()
  if &ft =~ "ruby"
    let s:urlTemplate = "http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8_ruby-v1.8/?q=%"
  else
    return
  endif
  let s:wordUnderCursor = expand("<cword>")
  let s:url = substitute(s:urlTemplate, "%", s:wordUnderCursor, "g")
  let s:cmd = "!open \"" . s:url . "\""
  execute s:cmd
endfunction

map <silent> <leader>d :call OnlineDoc()<CR>
```

coreyward, please don't use this, ha.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but for future googlers, I'd suggest 2 plugins:

1. [ri.vim](https://github.com/danchoi/ri.vim): to bring up offline `ri` docs within Vim.
2. [vim-ruby-doc](https://github.com/lucapette/vim-ruby-doc): to bring up online [rdoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/), [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/), or [rspec relish docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec) in a browser.

BTW If you're looking for CSS, DOM, HTML, JavaScript, JQuery, or PHP documentation check out my lil plugin [dochub.vim](https://github.com/stephenmckinney/vim-dochub).

Answer (score 1):

Install the [cheat sheets](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/) gem and simply shell out to access a quick help text.

```
:! cheat cheat
```

Rob Conery over at Tekpub.com uses this gem in his rails videos and it is quite useful.

Comment: Thanks tawman, the cheat gem looks cool. Not sure it will satisfy my needs (don't think it's trying to be complete documentation) but could be very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a browser to read online docs, because of hyperlinking. It makes it a lot easier to jump around between related pages.

Otherwise, I'll keep a terminal window open, for `ri` and `man` pages.

Also, inside vim, I'll open a separate tab and use that to view docs. That works pretty well because I don't have to shuffle splits.

The last two are old-school, but they work well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, try [dash.vim](https://github.com/rizzatti/dash.vim). Works for Rails and [lots of other frameworks and languages](http://kapeli.com/dash) as well.